# Node stuck at version 0.10.40

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to upgrade Node to v6.11.0 using the following instructions: https://www.abeautifulsite.net/how-to-upgrade-or-downgrade-nodejs-using-npm

I've used:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n 6.11.0
```

which resulted in:

```
install : node-v6.11.0
mkdir : /usr/local/n/versions/node/6.11.0
fetch : https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.11.0/node-v6.11.0-darwin-x64.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
installed : v0.10.40
```

It looks like I can't install a version of node greater than v0.10.40. The main reason why I'm trying to upgrade is that I'm receiving a error ('SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.') as seen here: https://github.com/Shopify/slate/issues/317

Comment: Probably find your node path needs updated - what do you see if you enter `which node` in the terminal?

Comment: This is too much hassle. Why not try a containerized version? There is a 6.11.5 readily available on docker hub. You can use the standard docker commands `docker run -it --rm -w /work -v /`pwd`:/work node:6.11.5-alpine npm build`

Comment: Why to try containerized version if someone don't need ? if someone have windows 7 then what to do .

Comment: Which os you have ?

Comment: 'which node' gives me: /usr/local/opt/nvm/v0.10.40/bin/node and I'm running mac os

Comment: @TimDonaldson so your using NVM....why are you installing Node via NPM? Sort of unclear on what it is you are trying to do here... if you want to update your node version open the terminal and type `nvm use <version>`